# Problem using enumerate environment in a proof newenvironment definition

Tags: lists, line-breaking, environments, theorems

I want to define a simple environment to enclose my proofs, actually I just wanted to put a little square right at the end. So, I made this new environment definition:

```
\newenvironment{Proof}{ \flushleft \textbf{PROOF}}{\rule{1ex}{1ex}}
```

When I use this environment to enclose simple text, then I get the little square right at the end, after the last character. The problem is when I enclose an `enumerate` environment because it adds a new line and put the little square at the beginning. In this case my problem is both I don't want the new line and also I need the square at the right ending of the margin. If I consider it this way

```
\newenvironment{Proof}{ \flushleft \textbf{PROOF}}{\begin{flushright} \rule{1ex}{1ex} \end{flushright}}
```

then a new line is always added.

Comment: I would consider doing what barbara suggests, there's a well-done `proof` environment. You suggest using a black box (`\rule{1ex}{1ex}`), this can be achieved too, by redefining `\qedsymbol`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`amsthm` automatically puts a box (an open box, but that can be redefined) flush right at the end of the last line of `proof`.  if the proof ends with a display or a list, then `\qedhere` can be used just before the end of that environment to move the box to the proper line.

to start the enumerated list on a new line after the proof header, enter it as

```
\begin{proof}
 \leavevmode
 \begin{enumerate}
 ...
```

documentation is available with `texdoc amsthm` (if you are using a system based on tex live) or by [visiting the page](http://www.ams.org/tex/amslatex) and clicking on the line "AMS theorem package user's guide".

to redefine the qed box,

```
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{...}
```

to change the main proof header,

```
\renewcommand{\proofname}{Whatever}
```

(thanks, egreg.)

for a one-time variant, just take advantage of the optional argument:

```
\begin{proof}[Proof of the XYZ theorem]
```

Comment: Great! how can exactly redefine the box?

Comment: Perfect!. Just a last question, sorry because I'm so new on this. How can I change the format of word "proof".

Comment: @DanielaDiaz `\renewcommand{\proofname}{Whatever}` if you don't use `babel`. If you use `babel` with language `spanish` (just as an example), `\addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\proofname}{Whatever}}`